# Support for using a proxy in capabilities?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

Is there support in appium for setting a proxy using a capabilities object? This is possible in selenium webdriver but doesn't seem to be working for me in appium.

WebDriver proxy example link:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible with the WebDriver, however you can either use Proxifier (with a way to change proxy ip on demand somehow) or write a NATIVE_APP code starting with

```
driver.start_activity( 'com.android.settings', '.wifi.WifiSettings', '.wifi.WifiSettings' )
action = TouchAction(driver)
action.long_press(x=72, y=250, duration=5000).release()
action.perform()
driver.find_element_by_name( 'Modify network' ).click()
driver.find_element_by_name( 'Show advanced options' ).click()
# write additional code
```

Some people setup Proxifier in such a way that, their master proxy (with a static IP) is setup with Proxifier and a slave Proxy ip can be changed via web or something.